# Maximizing usage of all CPU cores for python process

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, concurrency, multiprocessing

Here i'm splitting a list of data to the number of cores available and launching a process on them. The first method uses 100% of all cores fine, but the second one only runs on 40-50% on the cores. Any ideas on how could I speed them up? I've tried running it with multiprocessing.Pool(), with the concurrent.futures library, non of them could speed it up.

```
   #chunking list
    n = int(len(list) /  mp.cpu_count())

    chunks = [list[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(list), n)]

    processes = []
    print('Processing list on {0} cores...'.format(mp.cpu_count()))
    for chunk in chunks:
        p = mp.Process(target=process, args=[chunk])
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print('Creating and writing statistics for {0} individual domains...'.format(len(unique_list)))

    for p in processes:
        p.close()

    # chunking unique list
    n = int(len(unique_list) / mp.cpu_count())
    chunks2 = [unique_list[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(unique_list), n)]
    processes2 = []

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())

    for chunk in chunks2:
        p = mp.Process(target=statistics, args=[chunk])
        p.start()
        processes2.append(p)

    for p in processes2:
        p.join()
```

```
def process(list):
    for item in tqdm(list):
        if(check(list, item)):
            item = item.lower().split('@')[1]
            if item not in unique_list:
                unique_list.append(item)
# end of process

# statistics
def statistics(list):
    f = open("{0}/result.txt".format(dirname),"w+")
    for item in tqdm(list):
        if(domains.count(item) > 0):
            f.write("{0} | {1} \r\n".format(domains.count(item), item))
    f.close()
# end of statistics
```

Comment: Opening, closing and writing to files will all involve system calls, and synchronization. They _must_, because all your processes are writing to the same file, and the OS doesn't like data races affecting file contents. If your processes are all contending for the same resource, they can't all be running at full speed, can they?

Comment: Thank you, I switched the statistics method so it wouldn't use file operations, just a simple list assignment, but it's still just as slow...

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229643/4141279